# What is "TEEBITOEY" and how does it relate to this patent?

Tags: terminology

In reference to the patent: [US226542](https://www.google.com/patents/US226542)

The title of this patent is "TEEBITOEY" and I've found 62 other US patents that refer to this term, but I can't find a definition for it. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing 18 of those that I could find on the Internet, I don't think Teebitoey is a word, indeed I think it is a slight mistake that Google's OCR has made. [This excerpt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XsVYM5VY5acC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=TEEBITOEY&source=bl&ots=eyVSIGYD_1&sig=lK-EFuOhNc0mz57NeLqs5itJnfI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUs9jN9p7JAhVMNxQKHaXnDl0Q6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=TEEBITOEY&f=false) has the word TERRITORY at the top of the page, but Google has recognised it as TEEBITOEY.

[image]